# Why $E[X] = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}(i\times Pr\{X=i\})$ is equal to $E[X] = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}( Pr\{X \ge i \}))$

Tags: probability, statistics

If we have expectation $E[X] = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}(i\times Pr\{X=i\})$, where $i \in \mathbb{N}$. Can you please explain how is it equal to $E[X] = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}( Pr\{X \ge i \}))$?

I see that
$$
Pr\left[ X\ge i \right] =1-Pr\left[ X<i \right] 
$$
$$
Pr\left[ X<i \right] =\frac{1}{N}\times \frac{2}{N}\cdots \frac{i-1}{N}
$$
$$
Pr\left[ X\ge i \right] =1-\frac{1}{N}\times \frac{2}{N}\cdots \frac{i-1}{N}
$$
$$
=1-\frac{\left( i-1 \right) !}{N}
$$
$$
=\frac{N-\left( i-1 \right) !}{N}
$$
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}{\left( i\times Pr\{X=i\} \right)}=i\times \frac{i}{N}\ne \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}{\left( Pr\{X\ge i\} \right)}=\frac{N-\left( i-1 \right) !}{N}
$$

So, can you please correct if I am wrong? I am not able to get to formula that $E[X] = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}(i\times Pr\{X=i\})$, where $i \in \mathbb{N}$ is equal to $E[X] = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}( Pr\{X \ge i \}))$?.

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion that $Pr\left[ X<i \right] =\frac{1}{N}\times \frac{2}{N}\cdots \frac{i-1}{N}$? Also, what is $N$ in this scenario?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find the Mean for Non-Negative Integer-Valued Random Variable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/843845/find-the-mean-for-non-negative-integer-valued-random-variable)

Comment: one $P(1)$, two $P(2)$'s, three $P(3)$'s etc.

Comment: @BenGrossmann. Oh! I meant sum not product and $| \mathbb{N}|$ instead of $N$.

Comment: @Avra What exactly is $1/|\Bbb N|$ equal to?

Comment: @BenGrossmann.  Thank you. I meant here cardinality of set, which is infinity anyway. I realized that this does not work as we have infinity. If we have finite sum, then it's straightforward I guess as we can simply apply expectation rule.

Comment: A couple of prior similar questions were noted after my answer (one was actually noted while I was answering, but neither is really a duplicate, since those questions focus on different aspects of the formula). [$X:\Omega \to \mathbb{N}$ is random variable, How to prove that $E[x]=\sum_{i} \Pr(X\ge i)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1066141) is possibly closer in intent, but still not exactly the same since this question provides an attempt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^\infty Pr[X\ge i]
&=\sum_{i=1}^\infty\sum_{j=i}^\infty Pr[X=j]\tag1\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^\infty\sum_{i=i}^j Pr[X=j]\tag2\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^\infty j Pr[X=j]\tag3
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: write $Pr[X\ge i]$ as the sum of $Pr[X=j]$ for $j\ge i$
$(2)$: switch order of summation, keeping $j\ge i$
$(3)$: evaluate the inner sum

Comment: Very clear answer. Thank you.

Comment: So, changing order of sum was based on your observation of the fact that sequences are $p(x_1), \cdots,$. Second sequence, $p(x_2), \cdots,$. Third sequence, $p(x_3), \cdots,$ please?

Comment: No. The changing of the order of summation is simply that. All terms in the sum are positive, so we are allowed to change the order of summation, even in an infinite sum.